# Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Address;

Tags: java, android, sdk

I've seen this question asked about 100 times on StackOverflow, but this isn't a one answer that solves them all. Here is my build path:
[image: Java build path]

However I still get:

```
[2014-05-03 11:44:33 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Address;
[2014-05-03 11:44:33 - Untappd] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Address;
```

What is the best and easiest way to solve this issue? I got it when i tried to manually add a new version of Aviary SDK to my project by deleting the old project and adding the new one. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding and it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried removing the explicit `okhttp` dependency? If one of the other jar files is including that already, maybe you don't need it separately...

Comment: How do I explicit remove the dependency?

Comment: I hadn't spotted that that was the "private libs" part. Hmm. Not sure then :(

Comment: If I hover over the okhttp dependency - I can't remove it: http://im.grega.co/image/170K0I240j13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the problem, thanks to this reply by Joe Bowser (https://twitter.com/infil00p/status/462639837149798400). The problem here is the Aviary and Phonegap are both using the Lcom/squareup/okhttp framework, so I had to delete the okhttp framework from the CordovaLib directory, and re-run the project.

[image: CordovaLib has okhttp framework built it, and Aviary wants to use use it as well]

Comment: the issue was indead CordovaLib contain okhttp. **Okhttp < 2 for Cordova < 4**

Answer (score 1):

The multiple dex files error tells you that you are including the same class file from different sources. Please make sure you are not doing so. Check the libs folder too.

Comment: I guess that is what I am asking - how can I verify that? Here is the libs folder: http://im.grega.co/image/3H0e1s072l0T

Comment: The problem is in your CordovaLib directory.  It's already including okhttp source.  Try removing the okhttp source from that directory and try again. I've created an issue addressing this problem. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6630